# Can't set utf8 charset in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is my **php** file :

```
<?php
  define('HOST','localhost');
  define('USER','myUser');
  define('PASS','myPass');
  define('DB','myDb');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
  $sql = "insert into someTable (email,text,name,subject) values ('$email','$text','$name','$subject')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
     echo 'Sent successfully';
  }
  else{
     echo 'Unexpected error';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm sending some values from my **android** app to this php backend and this code will save my values to **MySQL** database.

It's working perfect but if i send values in non english language it shows values like this:
[image]

I've already set MySQL collation on **UTF-8** and I think the problem is from my php backend

**EDIT:**

I also tried solutions in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170) but it's not working.

Comment: What is the charset (not collation) of you database table? collation is used for sorting data, charset is used for storing data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @MarkBaker how to check this?

Comment: Look at the table definition: `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTableName`

Answer (score 3):

You had to set the collection to `utf8Persian-ci`.
Of course I also had a problem like yours, please refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47900943/8315608), I hope that can help you :)