# Insert persian value into a table with php code

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a value in a table . But when I am running below code , I see that shows this value with `????` . How can I solve this problem ?

insert.php

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $query = "INSERT INTO customer_tab (name,phone,address) VALUE ('آزاده','0981245','ایران کرمان')";
    $result = $connect->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "azadgh";
    $pass = "*******";
    $dbname = "my_db";
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname";
    try {
        $connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $connect->exec("SET character_set_connection = 'UTF8");
        $connect->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8");
        $connect->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo "unable to connect : " . $error->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What encoding do you use?

Comment: But did you check the table and column charset coding?

Comment: Missing single quote here. `$connect->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8");`. Which may solve the problem

Comment: check this:) This might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642755/insert-a-persian-text-in-mysql-table

Comment: user this function mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: The code was correct
I had to set the collection to `utf8Persian-ci` in DataBase

Answer (score 0):

TRy: `PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");`
Here is one solution that helped:
`$pdo->query("SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=NULL");<br>
$result = $pdo->query("select * from table");`

Answer (score 0):

I think database name is not reflecting in your code. Can you try to change your code like below,

```
$dbname = "my_db";
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname="+$dbname+";
```

or

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;
```

Comment: I have no problem for adding Latin values .